# OutlookExpress IStoreNamespace GetFirstSubFolder method fails on WinXP x64

Tags: c++, winapi, com

HRESULT error code - MSOEAPI_E_INVALID_STRUCT_SIZE

Works fine on WinXP x32.

Comment: make sure u have specified size of structure properly .

Comment: I used sizeof and it works in Win x32

Comment: Did you compile this code with the 64-bit compiler, targeting 64-bit systems, or are you just reusing the 32-bit code?

Comment: I recompiled with 64-bit compiler (VS 2005)

Comment: Did you override default structure packing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your targetting a 32bit version of OutlookExpress, maybe the packing of the FOLDERPROPS structure is different e.g. larger when you compile under 64-bit?